# Display each element of the dictionary on a new line working with Counter

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I have an array with random colors. There are duplicate elements. For example:

```
mass = ['white','black','white'...]
```

I need to count them so I've decided to use Counter:

```
mass_count = Counter(mass)
print (mass_count)
```

[What I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ID6F.png)

I want to display each element of the dictionary on a new line. I've used that code:

```
keys = [k for k in mass_count]
for i, key in enumerate(keys):      
    print("\n" + str(list(mass_count.keys())[i]) + ": " + str(mass_count[keys[i]]))
```

[What I've got #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ5pc.png)

Everything as I want except one thing: There are all elements displaying from max to min on my first result but this order is violated on the second result. So I want:

White: 22

Black: 14

Sky blue: 6

...

How can I achieve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `Counter.most_common()` [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)

```
for color, value in mass_count.most_common():
    print(f"{color}: {value}")
```